# how to do curl command with php

Tags: php, curl

i'm new to curl.
i have this curl code.
but i have no idea about run this with php

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file1.flac"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5"
```

this is my php code.but not sure that i'm correct.

```
$s = curl_init();
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5');
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
    '--header' => "Content-Type: audio/flac",
    '--data-binary' => '@audio-file1.flac'

]));
curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);
```

please help me how to add -u "{username}":"{password}" to php code?

Comment: `.but not sure that i'm correct`-> did you run your php CURL code? any error you get? what's is not correct?

Comment: api require userame and password (-u "{username}":"{password}") so i did't run.

Comment: { "code": 401, "error": "Not Authorized", "description": "No credentials supplied." }  i got only this

Comment: As your error message says, you need to supply credentials. If you dont have any, register with the API provider to get a username and password.

Comment: yes. i have username and password.but i'm not sure how to add it to php code

Comment: You could try https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: thank you .it's a nice service

Answer (score 1):

the *good* way to do this, is with a file handle and CURLOPT_INFILE, this will work with files of any size, and allows the upload to start before the entire file has been read from disk, thus it's faster and use just a small amount of memory, no matter how big the file is. however, the quick'n easy way, which puts the entire file in memory at once, and doesn't start the upload until the entire file has been read into ram,  and is thus unsuitable for big files, is simply: `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,file_get_contents($filename));`, but.. the rough equivalent to your curl command, using the good method, is:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
$filename = "audio-file1.flac";
$fileh = fopen ( $filename, 'rb' );
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "{username}:{password}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Content-Type: audio/flac' 
        ),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_INFILE => $fileh,
        CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => filesize ( $filename ),
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9&keywords=%22colorado%22%2C%22tornado%22%2C%22tornadoes%22&keywords_threshold=0.5",
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'libcurl/' . curl_version () ['version'] . '; php/' . PHP_VERSION 
) );
// curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, '127.0.0.1:9999' );
curl_exec ( $ch );
fclose ( $fileh );
curl_close ( $ch );
```